# Redis ready ReplyError: NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, socket.io

When i try to connect redis which based on redislab, i am getting following error **Redis ready ReplyError: NOAUTH Authentication required**.

```
const pubClient = createClient({ url: `${config.redisLabHost}:${config.redisLabPort}` });
pubClient.on('error', (e) => {
 console.log('Redis ready', e)
})
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
```

I followed the official documentation of socketio for redis usage

https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/

Comment: On top of the host and pretty, you need to provide your username and password when creating the client

Comment: where can i put the usernae and password ?   named parameter like url or passing on url itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to old redis console style, select the database from list. On configuration tab, you will see a default user password.

try the url link format like this redis://default:<default_password>@redis-123.redislabs.com:30011

```
const { createClient } = require("redis");
const pubClient = createClient(config.redisLabHost);
```